# Create an order column in a pandas dataframe based on one date column relative to another date column

Tags: pandas, rank

I have an extract where I'm required to identify a certain type of surgery `X` seen in the `Surg Type` column.

I need to retain medical appointments seen as distinct rows over a window/period of time, 3 appointment's prior (-3, -2, -1) and 3 appointment's post (+1, +2, +3)

I must include this order as an additional column.

On top of this I need to exclude any appointments outside of the window and any other type of `Surg Type`, in this example any surgery's denoted Z.

In this example 7/9 rows/record's I want retained and an additional column `Prior Post`

*** UPDATED EXAMPLE ***

```
Original Df

| Patient ID | Surg ID | Surg Type | Surg Date  | Medical Appt Date |
|------------|---------|-----------|------------|-------------------|
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2022-01-01        |
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2022-03-04        |
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2022-05-04        |
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2022-06-04        |
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2022-11-04        |
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2022-11-29        |
| 1          | 2       | Z         | 2022-12-01 | 2022-11-01        |
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2023-01-02        |
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2023-01-13        |



Desired Df

| Patient ID | Surg ID | Surg Type | Surg Date  | Medical Appt Date | Inclusion |
|------------|---------|-----------|------------|-------------------|-----------|
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2022-01-01        | Exclude   |
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2022-03-04        | -3        |
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2022-05-04        | -2        |
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2022-06-04        | -1        |
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2022-11-04        | 1         |
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2022-11-29        | 2         |
| 1          | 2       | Z         | 2022-12-01 | 2022-11-01        | -1        |
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2023-01-02        | 3         |
| 1          | 1       | X         | 2022-09-03 | 2023-01-13        | Exclude   |
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complex example? How should it generalize with more Patient IDs / Surg IDs?

Comment: @mozway thanks for providing more complex answer below, on reflection my example is at the medical appt level and all dates are populated within this column. I won't need to address NaT

Comment: got it, this is a bit different logic. Check the update below.

Comment: @mozway Brilliant thank you, works and now for me to get my head around the approach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the surgeries `X`, then compute the time difference between the appointment and the surgery and compute the [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) for negative and positive numbers per group with [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html). Finally, mask the ranks outside of threshold.

```
# number of medical appointments to keep before/after a surgery
N = 3

# columns to use a grouper
group_cols = ['Patient ID', 'Surg ID']

# ensure datetime
df[['Surg Date', 'Medical Appt Date']] = df[['Surg Date', 'Medical Appt Date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# custom function to compute the rank of the Appt Date
def flag_nearest(g, N):
    diff = g['Medical Appt Date'].sub(g['Surg Date'])
    m = diff>'0'
    ranks = (diff.where(m).rank()
             .fillna(-diff.mask(m).rank(ascending=False))
             # optional, to have integers in the output
             .astype(int).astype(object)
            )
    return ranks.where(ranks.abs()<=N, 'Excluded').to_frame()

# identify non-X rows
m = df['Surg Type'].eq('X')

# compute the rank and flag columns outside of threshold
df['Inclusion'] = (df[m].groupby(group_cols)
                        .apply(flag_nearest, N)
                        .droplevel(group_cols)
                        # optional, to fill the non-X
                        .reindex(df.index, fill_value='non-X')
                  )
```

Output:

```
   Patient ID  Surg ID Surg Type  Surg Date Medical Appt Date Inclusion
0           1        1         X 2022-09-03        2022-01-01  Excluded
1           1        1         X 2022-09-03        2022-03-04        -3
2           1        1         X 2022-09-03        2022-05-04        -2
3           1        1         X 2022-09-03        2022-06-04        -1
4           1        1         X 2022-09-03        2022-11-04         1
5           1        1         X 2022-09-03        2022-11-29         2
6           1        2         Z 2022-12-01        2022-11-01     non-X
7           1        1         X 2022-09-03        2023-01-02         3
8           1        1         X 2022-09-03        2023-01-13  Excluded
```

Extended example:

```
    Patient ID  Surg ID Surg Type  Surg Date Medical Appt Date Inclusion
0            1        1         X 2022-09-03        2022-01-01  Excluded
1            1        1         X 2022-09-03        2022-03-04        -3
2            1        1         X 2022-09-03        2022-05-04        -2
3            1        1         X 2022-09-03        2022-06-04        -1
4            1        1         X 2022-09-03        2022-11-04         1
5            1        1         X 2022-09-03        2022-11-29         2
6            1        2         Z 2022-12-01        2022-11-01     non-X
7            1        1         X 2022-09-03        2023-01-02         3
8            1        1         X 2022-09-03        2023-01-13  Excluded
9            2        1         X 2022-09-05        2022-01-01  Excluded
10           2        1         X 2022-09-05        2022-01-02  Excluded
11           2        1         X 2022-09-05        2022-03-04        -3
12           2        1         X 2022-09-05        2022-05-04        -2
13           2        1         X 2022-09-05        2022-06-04        -1
14           2        1         X 2022-09-05        2022-11-04         1
15           2        1         X 2022-09-05        2022-11-29         2
16           2        2         Z 2022-12-02        2022-11-01     non-X
17           2        1         X 2022-09-05        2023-01-02         3
18           2        1         X 2022-09-05        2023-01-13  Excluded
```

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

at first make datetime

```
df['Surg Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Surg Date'], errors='coerce')
df['Medical Appt Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Medical Appt Date'], errors='coerce')
```

make condition and use np.select

```
import numpy as np
cond1 = df['Surg Type'].eq('X')
cond2 = df['Surg Date'].gt(df['Medical Appt Date'])
cond3 = df['Surg Date'].lt(df['Medical Appt Date'])
s1 = (cond1 & cond2)[::-1].cumsum().mul(-1)
s2 = (cond1 & cond3).cumsum()

condlist = [~cond1 | s1.lt(-3) | s2.gt(3), cond2, cond3]

df['Inclusion '] = np.select(condlist, ['Exclude Row', s1[::-1], s2], np.NaN)
```

df:

[image]

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Patient ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'Surg ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1], 'Surg Type': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Z', 'X', 'X'], 'Surg Date': ['2022-09-03', '2022-09-03', '2022-09-03', '2022-09-03', '2022-09-03', '2022-09-03', '2022-12-01', '2022-09-03', '2022-09-03'], 'Medical Appt': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y'], 'Medical Appt Date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-03-04', '2022-05-04', 'NaT', '2022-11-04', '2022-11-29', 'NaT', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-13']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```