# Check all records in a pandas group specific column make up a predefined list of expected values

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe whereby I need to check whether each group contains a full complement of excepted values.

I have tried grouping by `Patient ID` and using `transform` to check that each group has all 6 required value(s) `Y` in `Inclusion` being: -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3 otherwise marked as `N`

Using `all` in a lambda doesn't quite get me there

Original df

| Patient ID | Surg ID | Surg Type | Surg Date | Medical Appt Date | Inclusion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | X | 2022-09-03 | 2022-03-04 | -3 |
| 1 | 1 | X | 2022-09-03 | 2022-05-04 | -2 |
| 1 | 1 | X | 2022-09-03 | 2022-06-04 | -1 |
| 1 | 1 | X | 2022-09-03 | 2022-11-04 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | X | 2022-09-03 | 2022-11-29 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | X | 2022-09-03 | 2023-01-02 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | X | 2022-10-03 | 2022-09-01 | -2 |
| 2 | 1 | X | 2022-10-03 | 2022-09-11 | -1 |
| 2 | 1 | X | 2022-10-03 | 2022-10-12 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | X | 2022-10-03 | 2022-10-29 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | X | 2022-10-03 | 2022-12-12 | 3 |

Desired df

| Patient ID | Surg ID | Surg Type | Surg Date | Medical Appt Date | Inclusion | IncludeYN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | X | 2022-09-03 | 2022-03-04 | -3 | Y |
| 1 | 1 | X | 2022-09-03 | 2022-05-04 | -2 | Y |
| 1 | 1 | X | 2022-09-03 | 2022-06-04 | -1 | Y |
| 1 | 1 | X | 2022-09-03 | 2022-11-04 | 1 | Y |
| 1 | 1 | X | 2022-09-03 | 2022-11-29 | 2 | Y |
| 1 | 1 | X | 2022-09-03 | 2023-01-02 | 3 | Y |
| 2 | 1 | X | 2022-10-03 | 2022-09-01 | -2 | N |
| 2 | 1 | X | 2022-10-03 | 2022-09-11 | -1 | N |
| 2 | 1 | X | 2022-10-03 | 2022-10-12 | 1 | N |
| 2 | 1 | X | 2022-10-03 | 2022-10-29 | 2 | N |
| 2 | 1 | X | 2022-10-03 | 2022-12-12 | 3 | N |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you necessarily have -1 before -2, 1 before 2, etc. (and no other values than those, like comments) then a simple [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `nunique` and checking that you have all `6` values:

```
df['IncludeYN'] = np.where(df.groupby(['Patient ID', 'Surg ID'])
                           ['Inclusion'].transform('nunique').eq(6),
                           'Y', 'N')
```

If you want to compare to a specific set of values with [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) and ignore possible external values (like `"Excluded"` from your other question):

```
target = {-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}

df['IncludeYN'] = np.where(df.groupby(['Patient ID', 'Surg ID'])
                           ['Inclusion'].transform(lambda x: target.issubset(x)),
                           'Y', 'N')
```

Output:

```
    Patient ID  Surg ID Surg Type   Surg Date Medical Appt Date  Inclusion IncludeYN
0            1        1         X  2022-09-03        2022-03-04         -3         Y
1            1        1         X  2022-09-03        2022-05-04         -2         Y
2            1        1         X  2022-09-03        2022-06-04         -1         Y
3            1        1         X  2022-09-03        2022-11-04          1         Y
4            1        1         X  2022-09-03        2022-11-29          2         Y
5            1        1         X  2022-09-03        2023-01-02          3         Y
6            2        1         X  2022-10-03        2022-09-01         -2         N
7            2        1         X  2022-10-03        2022-09-11         -1         N
8            2        1         X  2022-10-03        2022-10-12          1         N
9            2        1         X  2022-10-03        2022-10-29          2         N
10           2        1         X  2022-10-03        2022-12-12          3         N
```

Answer (score 5):

mozway's answer covers if you want either 6 unique values, or at least these 6 values. If you want these 6 and only these 6, this lambda works:

```
check_values = lambda x: set(x) == {-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}
df['IncludeYN'] = df.groupby('Patient ID')['Inclusion'].transform(check_values)
```

Comment: that's a good point which I might have needed to explain. I used `issubset` since in another question OP (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78096176)) inserted other comments in this column like `"Excluded"`, which should most likely not be considered ;)

Comment: got it, sounds like your answer is better for OP then!

Comment: @mozway Thanks both, I omit `Excluded` before applying your code above. Works perfectly. Again, I understand 80% of what I need to do but then can't think of the `nunique().eq(6)`